# Rank Feature selection on Multiple data frames in r

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to do a rank feature by importance using the caret package. When I try it on a single dataframe it works fine, but I'm having troubles when I try to apply it on multiple data frames. Here is my code:

```
require(mlbench)
require(caret)

# Mylist is the list of my data frames

# prepare the training scheme
control.mylist <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats =3)  

# train the model                                                      
model.mylist <- lapply(mylist, train, method = "knn", Industry_proximity~., preProcess = "scale", trControl = control.list.chempsetbio)
```

I want to use a column named Industry_prox as outcome to train my model (Industry_prox is the same column name on all my dataframes). But until now my code does not work

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have a reproducible example, so I created one using mtcars dataset.

```
library(caret)

df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- mtcars

mylist <- list(df1, df2)

# prepare the training scheme
control.mylist <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats =3)  


# train the model                                                      
model.mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) train(mpg ~., data = x, method = "knn",  preProcess = "scale", trControl = control.mylist))
```

For your code this last line should probably be the code below. But I noticed that your trControl in your code is different from the one you specified in the beginning.

```
model.mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) train(Industry_proximity~., data = x, method = "knn",  preProcess = "scale", trControl = control.mylist))
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works nicely. Thank you. And you were right i was using a different trControl on my code